# How to find cumulative mean/average of a matrix in Octave?

Tags: octave

How to find cumulative mean/average of a matrix in Octave? In matlab it is pretty simple. In octave I couldnt able to find.

Comment: What did you try in MATLAB that didn't work in Octave?

Answer (score 0):

The cumulative mean is going to simply be the cumulative sum (`cumsum`) divided by the number of elements into the array up until that point.

So for the data

```
A = [1 3 4 5 6];
```

We could do

```
out = cumsum(A) ./ ( 1:numel(A) );
```